# How to do a 'Report Bug' command with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I ve been trying to do a report 'bug command'.
This is my code so far:

```
bot.on('message', async (client, message, args) => {
    let parts = message.content.split(" ");

    if(parts[0].toLocaleLowerCase() == '!bugreport') {
        const owner = client.users.cache.get('567717280759283883');

        const query = args.join(" ");
        if(!query) return message.channel.send('Bitte schildere den Bug').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 5000}))
    
        const reportEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Fehlermeldung')
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
        .addField('Fehler:', query)
        .addField('Server:', message.guild.name, true)
        .setFooter(`Gesendet von ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
        .setTimestamp();
    
        owner.send(reportEmbed);
    }
});
```

The error code always says that 'content' is undefined, but I do not understand that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `bot` is a `Client`, it seems you're expecting [the `message` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) to pass more arguments than it actually does. Although that would indicate you're trying to read `content` from `undefined`, not that `content` itself is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Client#message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event allows 1 parameter which is an instance of `Message`. Change your code to this

```js
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
//code here
})
```

You probably got confused with message handlers, where you can customize the function to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The message event only passes the received message according to the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) docs.  Your event handler should look more like this at the start:

```js
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
```

Note this won't completely fix your command, as you'll still be missing the `args` and `client` parameters. Here's my best guess as to where to get those from based on how you're using them:

```js
const args = parts.splice(0,1); // gives array of everything after "!bugreport"
const client = bot; // alternatively, replace client with bot in your code
```